# How to get all owners of a given steam app?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I know you can get all the apps owned by a given profile. But what about the inverse operation? (I.e. given one app, listing all the profiles owning that app).

I'm aware that there could be millions of results and there's also limits for querying that, but I don't plan to get them in a single shot.

Additionally, even returning just the *online profiles* / *recently online* / *recently played* would be fine if that reduces the results size.

Any alternative approach for this will be considered.

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The reason is:

- "get all the apps owned by a given profile" > the user as specifically confirmed that this information is publicly available on their public Steam profile
- the default privacy settings are "friends only"
- Therefore most users who own an app did not consent to making this information public

To no surprise, there is **NO API** for what you want to do. Only Valve knows.

Comment: OK. I had seen a website listing the amount per app (approximated ranges), and that caught my attention.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: These websites use statistical inference to calculate an estimate. For example, SteamSpy makes this clear on their about page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get player ownership information about games that you are a **publisher** of using a combination of [GetPublisherAppOwnershipChanges](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamUser#GetPublisherAppOwnershipChanges) and [GetPublisherAppOwnership](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamUser#GetPublisherAppOwnership).

This will only give you the SteamIDs of people that own your games. You need a publisher API key for this and it will only work with the web API.